# php unable to display result webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having problem trying to get a web url working within php, I am basically getting  a list of content displayed, the list content becomes a links to a result webpage (detail.php). I want to display the result webpage with more detailed info. on the same webpage with a back button to original list.

```
=====
 my list webpage code
 =====

$c = 0; //Variable to keep count of categories
$servicetype = '$brand';    //variable declaration last displayed servicetype.   
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM <tablename>  ORDER BY serviceType, serviceName ASC";

   // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

    // Loop the recordset $rs

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    //If the servicetype name has changed, display it and update the tracking variable
    if ($servicetype != $row['serviceType']){
    $servicetype = $row['serviceType'];

 //If this isn't the first category, end the previous list.
    if ($c>0) echo "</ul>";

    echo '<h3>'.$row['serviceType'].'</h3><ul>'; // subheading & related content.
    $c++;
}

    $strName = $row['serviceName'];
    $strLink = "<a href = 'detail.php?id = " . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";

 // List link

   echo "<li>" . $strLink . "</li>"; 
  }

// Close the database connection

mysql_close();

?>
 ====
 my detail.php code below
 =====
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM gu_service_cat WHERE id = " . $_GET["id"];
  $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

    // Loop the recordset $rs

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

      // Write the detail data of the ID

    echo '<h3>ID:</h3>' . $row['ID'] . ' ' . $row['guUrl'] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>availability:</dt><dd>" . $row["availability"] . "</dd>";

}

//echo '<h3>'.$row['serviceType'].'</h3><ul>';

 // Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>
</dl>
   <p>
 <a href="main list webpage">Return to the list</a>
```

Comment: Whats your **exact** problem?

Comment: hi xatenev thanks for the quick response I am unable to get the link to open in the same webpage with more detailed information, any ideas...check my code thanks in advance....singhy

Comment: Also, maditory, '**mysql_*** functions are depricated. Please use **mysqli_***'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do see you incorectly using variable variables.

This is incorrect:

```
$servicetype = '$brand';
if ($servicetype != $row['serviceType'])
```

What you need to do is assign the variable `$servicetype` a string, in this case `'brand'` and use that in the if statement:

```
$servicetype = 'brand';
if ($$servicetype != $row['serviceType'])
```

Notice the double dollar sign. Read more about [Variable Variables](https://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: hi brett thanks for the quick response , tweaked the code ok,can not seem to get the url links from the list generated to work as per my list code, all seem to be working but can not pass the variable of id= to the result webpage (detail.php) any ideas....very confused, thanks in advance....singhy

Comment: thanks brett I am now getting a warning on line 34 (in the detail.php)Warning: Supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /detail.php on line 34....any ideas how to get this working !